# jQuery function used multiple times breaks site

Tags: javascript, jquery

*It's pretty hard to replicate because I use this code on a wordpress site and everything together gets to this result, but I try to explain it as good as possible.
I just want to know if I use it wrong or if its "illegal" to do it like I did so it would break something for sure, or if just wordpress or some other code on there messes this up.*

First I got the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let li = $('.wpb_image_grid_ul li').not('#studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul li');
    let width = li.outerWidth();

    li.css('height', width);
});
```

It resizes images inside my li to be square. It is working, but as soon as the browser gets resized and a breakpoint changes the width of the image, the height will stay the same as it got set before.

So I put my code in a function and called it once in the `$(document).ready(function ()` and once in the `$(window).resize(function()` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function gallery_fix () {

        let li = $('.wpb_image_grid_ul li').not('#studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul li');
        let width = li.outerWidth();

        li.css('height', width);
    }

    gallery_fix();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    gallery_fix();
});
```

But that breaks the site, when I resize the window the page isn't responsive anymore and most of the content overflows.

When I change the code to this and just duplicate everything instead of calling the function twice it's working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function gallery_fix () {
        let li = $('.wpb_image_grid_ul li').not('#studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul li');
        let width = li.outerWidth();

        li.css('height', width);
    }

    gallery_fix();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
        let li = $('.wpb_image_grid_ul li').not('#studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul li');
        let width = li.outerWidth();

        li.css('height', width);
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my code not in the correct syntax? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Although I would like to know why this is the case, if you got a more elegant way of checking if the browser resizes I would also appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `gallery_fix` function is declared inside your `$(document).ready()` function. So, you can only call the function from within. You can either:

1. place your `$(window).resize()` handler within the `$(document).ready()`
2. declare the `gallery_fix` function outside

Comment: Thank you. I try number 2. The first one didn't work on resize (but can't quite remember why). I try both

Comment: @skarpeta The resize handler should work even if declared in document.ready(), there might be a different problem.